# What should the teeth and jaw gape of my hypercarnivore humanoid species be like?

Tags: biology, aliens, humanoid, carnivorous

They also eat blood and bones. I was thinking the teeth should be serrated, like a T. rex's, but rexies had really long muzzles and while my species have a little bit of a muzzle, and square chins/strong jawlines/wide mouths, their faces are mostly flat like a human's.

Edit:// For aesthetics i suppose, about the serrated teeth. They might not need them. They're a race that's millions of years older than humans, with extremely advanced technology compared to ours. They use tools but it took them a much longer time in their species' history to learn how than it did for us.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with additional information? What is the average size of your humanoids? What terrestrial animal would be a good example of the type of food they'd eat whole (like wolves eating voles)? What, exactly, do you mean by "hypercarnivoran?" Considering dogs/wolves can eat whole creatures, why do you want serrated teeth (other than for aesthetics)? Finally, please remove the second question and ask it separately after this one has been answered. When you do ask it, explain what the cultural conditions are (are we animals in a forest or dining with the Queen?).

Comment: @JBH: [Hypercarnivore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercarnivore).

Comment: Actual real-life human *can* adopt a diet consisting of mostly meat; Eskimos are famous for this. For a faddish example, see Shawn Baker's [*Carnivore Diet*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/162860350X) (2019) (link goes to Amazon).

Comment: @AlexP The term "hypercarnivoran" is a nonsense term and may not refer to what you cited unless the OP made a typo. There are [carnivorans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivora), and there are hypercarnivores, but there are no such things as hypercarnivorans. "Carnivoran" is a taxonomic group and "hypercarnivore" refers to a dietary pattern.

Comment: @user2352714 yeah i guess i was mistaken with that term sorry

Comment: @AlexP Oh, I looked it up... I was encouraging the OP to bring the definition into his post.

Answer (score 2):

**Humans use tools.**

If you start with the premise that your creatures are humans, you can have them use tools to extend their phenotype such that it accomodates their diet.  Humans living on hard seeds and nuts don't need horse teeth.  They can use tools to crush up the seeds.  Humans living on marrow don't need hyena jaws.  They can use tools to crush up the bones.

https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/ancient-human-ancestors-may-have-grown-big-brains-scavenging-bone-marrow

> The hypothesis also suggests that if our early human ancestors
> scavenged marrow from carcasses, they would have used tools different
> from those used in the procurement of meat. Unlike slicing meat off a
> bone, which requires sharp cutting tools, obtaining marrow requires
> nothing more complicated than a heavy rock for pulverizing and
> splintering bone.

It is not as cool as having phenotypically freaky humans with hyena mouths.  If you want your hypercarnivore humans to look more carnivory, go ahead and make them that way.

---

I have to think that a good adaptation to a hypercarnivore diet humans would be hypercooperativity to take down big prey.  Humans already excel at that but you could make them better.

Comment: Increasing the unit cohesion would be far more impactful than mere teeth.

Answer (score 0):

To fit a human profile, I imagine a shortened version of any kind of predator with crushing molars, like a heavy dog, wolf, bear, hyena, or wolverine. Even a gorilla might fit the bill.